# Leaflet-search on multiplelayers won't work

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

Hey guys i got some problems with searching multiplelayers in leaflet-search by Stefano Cudini. First i will explain my problem and add the complete code at the end.

I already tried this:

```
var barLayer= new L.geoJson(bar).addTo(map);
var attraktionenLayer= new L.geoJson(attraktionen).addTo(map);

L.control.search({
layer: L.layerGroup([barlayer, attraktionenlayer]),
initialize: false,
propertyName: 'name',
buildTip: function(text, val) {
   var type = val.layer.feature.properties.amenity;
   return '<a href="#" class="'+type+'">'+text+'<b>'+type+'</b></a>';
   }
}).addTo(map);
```

I also tried to combine my layers before using L.control.search like this:

```
var poiLayers = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
poiLayers.addLayer(barLayer);
poiLayers.addLayer(attraktionenLayer);

//also tried this in a single command like

var poiLayers = L.layerGroup([barLayer,attraktionenLayer]).addTo(map);
```

But everytime i try to search something i get the following error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: m.getLatLng is not a function
at leaflet-search.js:571
at eachLayer (leaflet.js:7)
at e.<anonymous> (leaflet-search.js:570)
at eachLayer (leaflet.js:7)
at e._recordsFromLayer (leaflet-search.js:522)
at e._fillRecordsCache (leaflet-search.js:715)
at leaflet-search.js:677
```

For single layers the search is working and also if i get the arrays from my FeatureCollections and concat them like this:

```
var barsarray = bar.features;
var restaurantsarray = attraktionen.features;

var poiarray = barsarray.concat(restaurantsarray);
var poiLayer = new L.geoJson(poiarray);
```

But with this workaround i get all my markers on the map twice and if i want to hide the single layers with L.control.layers the poilayer will always be shown.

Any suggestions?

Complete Codeexample:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/leaflet-search.css" />
<script src="../src/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="../src/leaflet-search.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 1600px; height: 400px;"></div>


<script src="../data/Bars.js"></script>
<script src="../data/Attraktionen.js"></script>

<script>
    var map = L.map('map', {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new L.latLng(50.957703,6.967322),
        layers: L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
    });

    var barLayer= new L.geoJson(bar).addTo(map);
    var attraktionenLayer= new L.geoJson(attraktionen).addTo(map);



   var barsarray = bar.features;
   var restaurantsarray = attraktionen.features;

   var poiarray = barsarray.concat(restaurantsarray);

   var poiLayer = new L.geoJson(poiarray);

   var poiLayers = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
   poiLayers.addLayer(barLayer);
   poiLayers.addLayer(attraktionenLayer);

L.control.search({
    layer: poiLayers,
    initialize: false,
    propertyName: 'name',
    buildTip: function(text, val) {
        var type = val.layer.feature.properties.amenity;
        return '<a href="#" class="'+type+'">'+text+'<b>'+type+'</b></a>';
        }
   }).addTo(map);


 var baseLayers = {
        //"Bars": barsLayer,
        //"Restaurants": restaurantsLayer
 };

var overlays = {
    "Bars": barLayer,
    "Attraktionen": attraktionenLayer
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175863/adding-one-search-box-for-multiple-geojson-polygon-layers (which led to [Leaflet-search issue #95](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/issues/95) and [PR#101](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/pull/101))

Comment: First of all thanks four you suggestion but this seems not to work fort me as well. Now im getting an _getpath is not a function:

   ```Uncaught TypeError: this._getPath is not a function
        at e.searchInLayer (Index.html:99)
    at eachLayer (leaflet.js:7)
    at e.searchInLayer (Index.html:124)
    at eachLayer (leaflet.js:7)
    at e._recordsFromLayer (Index.html:128)
    at e._fillRecordsCache (leaflet-search.js:715)
    at leaflet-search.js:677```

Maybe any other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe its easier just to get all data in a single layer and not show the markers on the map? I tried this also but cant find any option not to display the markers.